# Why was Fiona shaving her face at the beginning of Shrek 2?

Tags: shrek

At the beginning of Shrek 2, both Shrek AND Fiona were shaving their faces.

Why was FIONA doing it? Do ALL ogres in this universe shave their faces, regardless of gender?

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/fashion/2021/apr/19/female-shaving-why-women-are-removing-their-facial-hair-from-chin-growth-to-peach-fuzz

Answer (score -3, accepted):

All ogres grow hair everywhere. Most dont shave

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this, especially in relation to female ogres?